# Use the webpack asset module with a custom output filename

Tags: javascript, webpack

Suppose I had the following webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        assetModuleFilename: "assets/[name][ext]",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
    //...
    ],
};
```

My question is how can I separate the fonts from the images? I want to put each one in a subdirectory called "fonts" and "images" under the assets folder. I know this is possible using the "file-loader". However, I want to use the asset module.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`Rule.generator.filename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rulegeneratorfilename) property:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...

  module : {
    rules : [
      // ...

      // Fonts
      {
        test      : /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\w+)?$/,
        type      : 'asset/resource',
        generator : {
          filename : 'fonts/[name][ext][query]',
        }
      },
    ]
  },

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Worth to mention that `Rule.generator.filename` can also be a function like this `filename: (pathData) => { /* do whatever */ return filename }`. The `pathData` holds lots of useful information, like `pathData.module.resourceResolveData`. This way it's possible to return different filenames for different conditions on the current module/resource.

Comment: @szegheo I did not find that in the docs, do you know where it is documented? The docs [I found](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rulegeneratorfilename) only mention an object not a function. When I tried a function I got an error. Webpack 5.

Comment: @lonix Indeed, it's hard to find, but if you follow the "The same as..." links, you can get to `https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename` where it is documented.

Answer (score 4):

This should be OK.

```js
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              name: '[hash:8].[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|tiff)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              name: '[hash:8].[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: I want to use just the new webpack 5, asset modules as explained here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/ they are a replacement for the old raw, file, and url loaders.

Comment: @swampblues You can use file-loader in webpack 5, https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#outputpath

Comment: Yes, but at the very top of your link it says "DEPREACTED for v5: please consider to migarte on asset modules.". And that is what I'm trying to do. I want to migrate to using the new "asset modules" module explained here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Comment: @swampblues I am outdated, you can try this. `Rule.generator.filename` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rulegeneratorfilename

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for